# Failed to apply CSS via class attribute in XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

If I read in XML via jQuery, I can't apply CSS rules to contained elements via their `class` attributes.

Example:

I have the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="alpha">won't be found by CSS!</div>
```

I load it via AJAX to my HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'snippet.xml',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'xml',
      timeout: 10000,
      error: function() { alert('Error loading XML document'); },
      success: function(xml) {
        $(xml).find('div.alpha').each(function() {
          $(this).appendTo($('#result'));
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Then, I have the following CSS:

```css
.alpha {
    color: red;
}
```

Finally, the original HTML looks like this (before appending):

```html
<div class="alpha">will be found by CSS!</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

So in the end, there will be two divs with `class=alpha`. The miracle is CSS will be applied to the first one but not the second, which comes from the XML input. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the **full** rendered HTML + CSS definitions. It's impossible. your html is probably invalid

Comment: If you're sending back HTML, you should send it as HTML, not as XML.

Comment: jQuery desperately needs a `$.ajah()` method and a `$a.ajaj()` method, now.

Comment: @Boltclock: if you mean something that expects HTML or javascript in its return then you can use the dataType to tell it what it is going to get back... This might be useful to do here to change the datatype to "xml html" which by my reading should assume it receives XML and then convert it to HTML. I don't know if it will help but I can only imagine that the fact its treating it as HTML instead of XML is causing the problems... (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for docs)

Comment: @Chris: I'm aware of that. I was just making fun of how the name `$.ajax()` refers to Asynchronous JavaScript and **XML** :)

Comment: @Boltclock: Ah, I see. It seems that its monday and my joke detection is just failing. ;-) I generally just ignore the X for XML anyway. I am not convinced it was every really that XMl focussed apart from maybe right back at the start but that's when nobody used it anyway. I tend to forget about the XML bit and amusingly am more suprised when somebody does use it than anything else. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HTML is not XML.** As Ryan P said, if you're sending a response in HTML, the easiest solution is to actually send it as HTML, not XML.

But if you need to send HTML markup in an XML response for whatever reason, the *proper* way to do it is to put the HTML in a CDATA section, and read that CDATA section. Here's a modified `snippet.xml` for example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <html><![CDATA[<div class="alpha">will also be found by CSS!</div>]]></html>
</response>
```

Then, use jQuery's `.find()` method to retrieve the XML `<html>` element, get its text, then append that text into `#result`. Here's the modified `success` callback:

```js
success: function(xml) {
  $(xml).find('html').each(function() {
    var html = $(this).text();
    $(html).appendTo($('#result'));
  });
}
```

The `.appendTo()` call with the `html` string will look like this:

```js
$('<div class="alpha">will also be found by CSS!</div>').appendTo($('#result'));
```

So it will work, giving you this resulting HTML:

```html
<div class="alpha">will be found by CSS!</div>
<div id="result"><div class="alpha">will also be found by CSS!</div></div>
```

---

Here's some explanation of what's happening in the question, for anyone interested (substitute "HTML" with "XHTML" if you prefer):

Your XML `<div>` element is not an HTML `<div>` element; it is just an XML `<div>` element with no semantic meaning whatsoever. Therefore, the `class` attribute in your XML has no semantic meaning at all either.

The class selector in CSS doesn't just select any element by an attribute named `class` — the selector for that would be the attribute selector `[class~="alpha"]`, not `.alpha`. What a class selector matches in an XML document depends on whatever the XML namespace considers a class attribute, which may or may not be named `class`. [See the spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html)

Here's what's actually generated when jQuery sends your XML back to your page:

```html
<div class="alpha">will be found by CSS!</div>
<div id="result"><div xmlns="" class="alpha">won't be found by CSS!</div></div>
```

Notice the blank `xmlns` attribute? That's what turns the second `div` element into an element of some completely unknown, or should I say *nonexistent* XML namespace ([the `xmlns` attribute cannot be blank](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#iri-use), by the way).

So, since the second `div` is no longer an HTML element, the class selector in your CSS won't match it, because its `class` attribute no longer possesses the correct semantics in order to be matched (as there is no XML namespace defined for this element).

Why does jQuery's class selector here work then?

```js
$(xml).find('div.alpha').each(function() {
  $(this).appendTo($('#result'));
});
```

That's because jQuery converts the XML response to HTML as a DOM object, *then* executes the selector on the DOM object, which works because jQuery's class selector just asks for an element's `className`. However, what's actually appended is appended as XML, not HTML.

Comment: Ah. Very interesting. Do you think that setting the datatype to "xml html" might help as an alternative if the response cannot be changed to plain HTML? I've not got anythign to easily test with right now but it looks like it should try to interpret it as HTML instead of XML and thus may avoid the problems you've described.

Comment: @Chris: Tried that, no luck. jQuery just silently fails at `$(xml)` when I do that.

Comment: @Chris: No problem. The best bet here, really, is to send it as HTML. An XML document with a `<div>` element just means "This is an XML document with a root element called `<div>`". It doesn't say anything about HTML.

Comment: I assume then that if you toString the XML doc before you load it into jquery that the toString still puts the xmlns stuff in? It does seem in some ways silly that its not easy to deal with something like this. But I suppose transferring HTML as XML is much more wrong... :)

Comment: Is there a possibility to transfer a xml-div (<div xmlns="" class="alpha">) before appending into a html-div (<div class="alpha">) that will be found by css?

Comment: @shcnix: If you really need to send HTML in an XML response, I added a solution for that to my answer.